# Qt integer array model

Tags: arrays, qt, user-interface, integer

For instance, to represent a `QStringList` int GUI listview we just create a `QStringListModel` and bound it to the GUI. [example here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJf-vZ6FQfc).

In my case i have a file filled with integers, what i whant to do is parse the file into my memory for instance in integer array so i could work with data. Now, how do i bound this data to my gui, and if integer array is not apropriate, what kind of data structure should i choose?

```
int array[3] = {1,3,2};
model = new Q***Model(this);
model->set***(array);
```

Comment: I guess it would be easiest to fill a [QStandardItemModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qstandarditemmodel.html#details)

Answer (score 0):

To bound custom data to a view you need QStandardItemModel along QStandardItem, using that combination should also eliminate the need to use an array to store your file input.
[QStandardModelItem](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qstandarditemmodel.html#details)

Comment: 'model=new QStandardItemModel(size); for(int i =0; i <9; i++){ QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(string); model->setItem(i,item);}' where size is your array size and string is your string data

Answer (score 0):

You Can Simply Convert the integers to string, Create a Qlist of Standard item model Using the Strings gotten from the integer . Assign to each Standard item its integer data; Than append the standard item to the qlist. Check http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qstandarditem.html#setdata

several ways to Convert to string http://www.qtforum.org/article/24878/convert-int-to-qstring.html

Comment: this will not work for me, because basicly what my program does is sorts an array using number of different algorhytms. And the array might be long. I need to keep this low-level